# Marionette: Uncaught TypeError: * is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, marionette

I am reading [Marionette gentle introduction](http://samples.leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction-sample.pdf) book. I am following **Displaying a Model** chapter and have following code:

```
ContactManager.ContactView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#contact-template"
});

ContactManager.on("start", function(){
    var alice = new ContactManager.Contact({
        firstName: "Alice",
        lastName: "Arten",
        phoneNumber: "555-0184"
    });

    var aliceView = new ContactManager.ContactView({
        model: alice
    });

    ContactManager.regions.main.show(aliceView);
});

ContactManager.start();
```

and following element in html page:

```
<script type="text/template" id="contact-template">
    <p><%- firstName %> <%- lastName %></p>
</script>
```

I receive error: `Uncaught TypeError: ContactManager.Contact is not a constructor`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need to declare your model first before crating it's instance

```
ContactManager.ContactView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#contact-template"
});

ContactManager.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```